Как отфильтровать данные в базе данных SQLite по дате их добавления в базу(SQLiteStudio)?
мне нужно отфильтровать данные от новых к старым, это возможно?

"Отфильтровать" значит исключить какую-то часть данных, не соответствующих условию.  Судя по описанию, вам нужно упорядочить / отсортировать данные по требуемому полю (дате добавления).  Для сортировки в SQL-запросе к вашим данным следует использовать ORDER BY.

Если в таблице есть поле, в котором сохраняется дата добавления, или иные данные, прямо или косвенно устанавливающие срок/порядок добавления (например, автоинкрементное поле) - можно. Иначе - нет.

При условии что в таблице есть столбец содержащий дату добавления.
Допустим это столбец date_added (TIMESTAMP)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, date_added
FROM table_a
ORDER BY date_added;

